# Lennard-Jones potential

Tags: forces, energy, atomic-physics

For the Lennard-Jones interatomic potential, the portion of the graph between r = sigma and r = equilibrium has a negative potential energy (attraction) and a negative force (repulsion). I am trying to reconcile these two.

Comment: Well, how can you have a minimum in the potential without that feature?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you think there is to "reconcile" here?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really a fundamental physics question here, just a matter of terminology. The terms "attraction" and "repulsion" may refer either to the sign of the potential energy of interaction between the two atoms (relative to a zero defined at infinite separation), or to the sign of the force between the atoms (pulling them together or pushing them apart). People may use either definition, depending on the context.

In fact, for Lennard-Jones, there is even a third usage: people sometimes refer to the $r^{-6}$ term as the attractive part, and the $r^{-12}$ term as the repulsive part.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, the sign of the energy usually does not have any significance, since you can always add or subtract an arbitrary constant potential without changing the physics. Therefore, the only thing telling you the dynamics of the system is the derivative of the energy, which is clearly repulsive in the very close regime of the Lennard-Jones potential.
Purely for practical reasons, the energy of this potential is chosen so that $U(\infty) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The potential and force look like this:

[image]

Where the vertical line is the minimum of the potential, i.e. where the force is zero.

Left of that point, the force is "positive" hence repulsive => towards the right, i.e. to positive $r$ 
 Right of that point the force is "negative" hence attractive => left of that point, i.e. to negative $r$.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you everyone! On this graph, assuming two identical atoms, where would the van der Waals radius be? At the energy minimum?

Comment: Do you have an exact definition for van der Waals radius?

Comment: The distance of closest approach between two identical particles. Some sources say this occurs at the minimum of the Lennard-Jones potential, while others say this minimum is some (small) multiple of this distance.

Comment: I don't know what is meant by that - the distance of closest approach, usually also referred to as *impact parameter* in scattering theory, depends on the momentum as well. I think what you mean is in the context of hard sphere atoms - basically how close can you squish them together. Well this depends on the type of atom (fermion or boson), but the sharp repulsive potential on the left is due to the Pauli Exclusion principle.

Comment: Yes, in the context of the hard sphere model. I believe I have a better understanding, thank you for your help.